# Validity of Ampere circuital law

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, maxwell-equations

I read that the line integral in Ampere circuital law is applicable for a piece-wise continuous curve (loop). My question is whether the law is valid only for planar loops or does it hold good even for non-planar loops?

$$\oint B\cdot d\ell~=~ \mu_0I$$

Comment: This question is similar to mine. But doesn't answer mine. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/177840/

Comment: Do you understand how to derive this law from Maxwell’s equations and Stokes’ Theorem?

Comment: @G.Smith No I don't know how to drive it from Stoke's law.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampère%27s_circuital_law#Ambiguities_and_sign_conventions): “If the loop does not lie in a single plane...” (Previous link was wrong. Sorry.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The law you state is valid for *any closed* loop (in vacuum and for static electric fields) where $I$ is then the total current running through the loop. However, the expression is only convenient to use, if you have symmetries that allow you to carry out the integral. Therefore, in many text books you only see it applied for planar loops.

The classic example where this law is convenient is the magnetic field around a straight wire. In that case, you place your loop in a *planar* circle a distance $r$ from the wire and you argue by symmetry that the magnetic field must be the same on the entire loop and hence,

$$\oint \mathbf{B}\cdot d\mathbf{l} = 2\pi r B $$.

You then arrive at the well-known expression $B = \frac{\mu_0 I}{2\pi r}$ for the magnetic field around a straight wire. It is emphasized that the law you state is still valid for any strange loop around the wire (and not around the wire), but the integral then becomes very difficult to evaluate.